# Why the token rule (in ANTLR) " IDENT : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*; " does not recognize "x y z"?

Tags: antlr, whitespace, grammar, lexer

Say I have a piece of ANTLR grammar (lexer part)

```
fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
INTEGER : DIGIT+ ;
Ident : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;
WS : (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
COMMENT : '//' .* ('\n'|'\r') {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

I am thinking that, since WS eats all the white spaces between token, both "x  y  z" and "xyz" should have been recognizied as the same token of Ident. But apparently only "x y z" will be considered as  3 Ident. So I really feel confused about the behavior when white space is encountered for a lexer rule.

More concretely,  I have a rule

```
VARIABLE: ('A'..'Z')+ DIGIT*  ;
```

I want it to recognize variables identities like X3, Y4, XX55, etc. But surprisingly, this rule recognizes " X   Y" So this seems to be totally incomprehensible. What is your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you've put `WS` on the `HIDDEN` channel, `"x y z"` are three `Ident` tokens since the `WS` tokens are only discarded in parser rules, *not* inside lexer rules.

> More concretely,  I have a rule
>
> ```
>    VARIABLE: ('A'..'Z')+ DIGIT*  ;
> ```
>
> I want it to recognize variables identities like X3, Y4, XX55, etc. But surprisingly, this rule recognizes " X   Y" So this seems to be totally incomprehensible. What is your idea?

No, the rule `VARIABLE` does not match `" X   Y"` (including spaces): you must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`Ident : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;` means that an *Ident* is a letter followed by zero or more letters or digits. **NO whitespaces!**
That's why "x y z" are recognized like 3 *Ident*

Comment: Thanks. But. why you say NO Whitespaces?  I have a WS rule that recognizes it.

Comment: The WS rule matches the 2 spaces between: (`x` and `y`) and (`y` and `z`)